# After deployment, Grails tags, Redirections not working

Tags: html, css, grails, redirect, tags

I have a **Grails** application that works fine while on local server. and when I deploy it on my remote/cloud server; it works fine, when accessed from its IP; lets say `286.90.90.90:8080/ibuyarticle`, it works fine if we access it from IP, but when a domain name is associated with it; lets say `www.ibuyarticle.com`, then landing page is fine but no CSS is included. (When I see page source CSS is included like

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/ibuyarticle/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
```

But it must be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
```

And in all tags including `<a>` tag there is

```
<a href="/ibuyarticle/home/userAdminRegister" class="banner-register">Register</a>
```

This happens in every tag like `<img>` tag and all others. How to get rid of this problem. I m not being able to find out where I went wrong.

Comment: What are your values of the `grails.serverURL` and `grails.app.context` properties in `Config.groovy`? Where and how do you map the domain to your IP?

Comment: grails.serverURL = `ww.ibuyarticle.com ` and i havent used grails.app.context property

Comment: actually i have given link to my app, but i cant post the full address here like http:// coz this converts it into link :)

Comment: anybody please answer this

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `grails.app.context` for production is set to `/ibuyarticle`.

So all links get the `ibuyarticle` prefix.

Adjust your settings in `Config.groovy`:

```
environments {
    production {
        grails.app.context = '/'
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

And in your Apache settings remove the `ibuyarticle` from the `URL`, so that you just pass to `286.90.90.90:8080`:

```
<VirtualHost 216.70.92.108:80 >
    ...
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia On
    <Location / >
            ProxyPass http://216.70.92.108:8080/
            ProxyPassReverse http://216.70.92.108:8080/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: My apache settings is <VirtualHost 216.70.92.108:80 >
    ServerName "ibuyarticle.com"
 ServerAlias "www.ibuyarticle.com"
    ServerAlias "ipv4.ibuyarticle.com"
    ServerAdmin "webmaster@dosurfin.com"
    UseCanonicalName Off
 ProxyPass / http://216.70.92.108:8080/ibuyarticle/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://216.70.92.108:8080/ibuyarticle/
</VirtualHost>
Business-Class Web Hosting by (mt) Media Temple
216.70.92.108

Comment: Changing grails.app.context didnt worked for me... the above is my apache settings.... i am new to apache....

Comment: My config.groovy in prodyction mode is production {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
        grails.app.context = "/"
        grails.serverURL = "http://aplication address"

    }

Comment: I've added a sample apache setting according to your comment, remember to restart apache after updating your settings ...